# Удаление и обновление записи в Laravel выкидывает 404 ошибку

Tags: laravel

Есть сущность проект, эта сущность может приадлежать двум другим, пользователю и компании

Все пользовательские проекты выводятся по маршруту

```
Route::get('/profile/{user:slug}/projects', [AdminProjectController::class, 'userProjects'])->name('userProjects');
```

А проекты относящиеся к компании

```
Route::get('/profile/{user:slug}/companies/{company:slug}', [AdminCompanyController::class, 'detailCompany'])->name('detailCompany');
```

Любой проект можно обновить и удалить, тк проекты одинаковы то за удаление отвечает один метод `delete`

```
public function delete(User $user, Project $project)
{
    $project->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

И его маршрут

```
Route::delete('/profile/{user:slug}/projects/{project:slug}', [AdminProjectController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete.project');
```

Так вот, если я удаляю проект который относится к сущности пользователя, то все ок, после удаление редиректит обратно. Но как только я пытаюсь обновить или удалить проект из под компании, я сразу же получаю 404 ошибку, меня перекидывает на маршрут удаления или изменения проекта, сам проект не удаляется

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
Route::delete('/profile/{user:slug}/projects/{project:slug}', [AdminProjectController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete.project');
```

Надо было юзать

```
Route::delete('/profile/{user:slug}/projects/{project}', [AdminProjectController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete.project');
```